# Update SQLAlchemy relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two relationships to the same table. When I add an element to one relationship, this does not reflect to the other relationship until I submit the session. Is there a way to force "update" the relationships?

**Concrete example:**

```
class Event(ManagerBase):
    """Defines an event."""

    __tablename__ = 'eventing_events'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(EventingDevice.id), nullable=False)
    device = relation(EventingDevice)
    type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(EventType.id), nullable=False)
    type = relation(EventType)
    datetime = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    summary = Column(String(500))

    fields = relation("EventFieldValue",
                      viewonly=True,
                      collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("field.name"))

class EventFieldValue(ManagerBase):
    """The value of a single field of an event."""

    __tablename__ = 'eventing_event_field_values'

    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Event.id), primary_key=True)
    event = relation(Event, backref=backref("field_values",
                                            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("field")))
    field_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Field.id), primary_key=True)
    field = relation(Field)
    value = Column(Text)
```

I have two realations from `Event` to `EventFieldValue`: `fields` and `field_values` (via backref of event). When I add a EventFieldValue to `event.field_values`, it does not reflect in `event.fields` until I commit the session.

Comment: Have you tried to `flush()` your session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two relations, sqlalchemy have to make requests for each one, and doesn't share their cache in the session.

You should take a look at [Association proxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html), that seems to be exactly what you need. They allow you to define only one relation and to put proxies on the top of them to access stuff in the relation more easily.

Comment: I already thought about it, but I did not find any way to use the collection class dictionary just in the proxy and not in the relation itself. Can you figure out such a solution?

Comment: Do you really need to access ``EventFieldValue`` from ``Event``, can't it just be hiddent like in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#proxying-to-dictionary-based-collections or http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#composite-association-proxies ?

Comment: It can be hidden, but I would like to have `eventfieldvalue.field.name` as a key in the collection for `fields` and `eventfieldvalue.field` as a key in the collection for `field_values`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that this is much more complex that I initially though (and I overestimated ``association_proxy``). There's probably a way to do this without 2 relations, but you may have to take a closer look at the collection configuration. I don't think your can solve your problem without messing with the commits while keeping 2 relations.

Comment: Thank's for your help. I'm currently writing an overload of AssociationProxy. I will post it here, if it does work.

Comment: I actually wrote a separate proxy for this, as inheriting from AssociationProxy seemd to be to tricky: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11212883/145013

Answer (score 0):

[Flushing](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#flushing) the session should solve this problem. It updates your session with all the new state but doesn't do a commit. You can also look into [Refresh/Expire](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#refreshing-expiring) which will reload your objects.

Comment: No, does not work. As the relation won't be inserted in the db, reselecting it would not change anything, I guess.