# Change collection class key of reference in association_proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to change the key of the collection class of a reference in an association proxy?

**Example:**

```
class Event(ManagerBase):
    """Defines an event."""

    __tablename__ = 'eventing_events'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(EventingDevice.id), nullable=False)
    device = relation(EventingDevice)
    type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(EventType.id), nullable=False)
    type = relation(EventType)
    datetime = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    summary = Column(String(500))

    fields = association_proxy("field_values", "value")

class EventFieldValue(ManagerBase):
    """The value of a single field of an event."""

    __tablename__ = 'eventing_event_field_values'

    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Event.id), primary_key=True)
    event = relation(Event, backref=backref("field_values",
                                            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("field")))
    field_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Field.id), primary_key=True)
    field = relation(Field)
    value = Column(Text)
```

In this case, the `field` attribute of `Event` will represent a dict with `EventFieldValue.field` as a key. Is it possible to change this key only in the proxy itself without affecting the releationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as this is not possible with the original SQLAlchemy `AssociationProxy`, as the class accesses the original relationship directly, so any key will be queried 1:1 on the underlying relationship.

I wrote a class `DictProxy`, which allows changing the key as well as the value fields:

```
class DictProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, col, keyattr, valattr = None):
        self.obj = None
        self.col = col
        self.keyattr = keyattr
        self.valattr = valattr

    def __get__(self, obj, class_):
        self.obj = obj
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        outdict = {}
        for k, v in getattr(self.obj, self.col).iteritems():
            if not k is None:
                if self.valattr == None:
                    outdict[getattr(k, self.keyattr)] = v
                elif v is not None:
                    outdict[getattr(k, self.keyattr)] = getattr(v, self.valattr)
                else:
                    outdict[getattr(k, self.keyattr)] = None
        return repr(outdict)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        keyobj = [obj for obj in getattr(self.obj, self.col) if getattr(obj, self.keyattr) == key]
        if not len(keyobj):
            return None
        if self.valattr == None:
            return getattr(self.obj, self.col)[keyobj[0]]
        else:
            return getattr(getattr(self.obj, self.col)[keyobj[0]], self.valattr)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return len([obj for obj in getattr(self.obj, self.col) if getattr(obj, self.keyattr) == key]) != 0

def dict_proxy(*arg):
    return DictProxy(*arg)
```

**Example usage:**

```
class Event(ManagerBase):
    """Defines an event."""

    __tablename__ = 'eventing_events'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    device_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(EventingDevice.id), nullable=False)
    device = relation(EventingDevice)
    type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(EventType.id), nullable=False)
    type = relation(EventType)
    datetime = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    summary = Column(String(500))

    fields = dict_proxy("field_values", "name", "value")
```

`fields` of `Event` now is a dictionary with `EventFieldValue.name` as a key and accesses the relation field_values (which comes into from `EventFieldValue` via `backref`).

**Note:**
Actually this is a readonly proxy, but it might be possible (although tricky) to extend the proxy via a `__setitem__` method.